# WSO2 integration with Azure AD - 403 when accessing https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me

Tags: azure, wso2, azure-active-directory, wso2-identity-server

Currently I'm working on integration of WSO2 (5.8.0) and AzureAD using Office365 authenticator (ver. 1.0.6). I see in the logs that authenticator is at least doing something but from Azure side Im getting exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me
```

On Azure I set delegated permissions to Exchange APIs checking everything in my application.
I also checked Graph API but still without success. What permission should be granted to allow my app to access https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me?

Comment: A similar question was raised here as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39932422/required-scopes-for-https-outlook-office-com-api-v2-0-me

Comment: Yes already tried different permissions but still without success, however if I change authentiication method from Office365 authenticator to oauth2/openid then Im able to get the token, whats the difference between them?

Comment: Office365 authenticator is a dedicated connector for configuring AzureAD as Federated IDP using OpenID Connect. This authenticator is using this  https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me endpoint to get user attributes by default .But OAuth2/OpenID Connect Configuration is common for all OIDC federated IDPs. Under this  OAuth2/OpenID Connect Configuration you need to configure each endpoints of the OIDC federated IDP

Comment: Any update for this issue?

Comment: I switched to openId in WSO2 instead of office365 authenticator and it now works fine.

Comment: Any update for this issue？

Answer (score 0):

To access `https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me`, you will need `https://outlook.office365.com/User.Read` permission.

[image]

And you need to add the access token in the request header. If you have done this all correctly, please show us how you got the access token.